# It seems I cannot use JS code from CDN import

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML buttons, each linked to a specific JavaScript function. The first button triggers a function codded like so:

```
function add() {
  var newScript = document.createElement("script");
  newScript.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js";
  document.head.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

The second button triggers the following function:

```
function draw() {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In function number 2, I am using a sample from [www.chartjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org). To work, it needs the page to have loaded the script referred to in the first function.

After clicking on the button 1 then on the button 2, I am expecting to see in my head element a script element, src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js, which I do see, via the browser console.

On my page, I am expecting to see (after clicking on my second button) a graph, produced by the ChartJS code. This very element is missing. Instead, I have an error in my console, saying: 'Chart is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.draw'

Why do I have this error? Why is my chart not showing up?

Thank you for stopping by :) (y)

Comment: Can you show how you call add()? My guess the problem is with that.

Comment: Have you made sure the script has fully loaded in before hitting the second button?

Comment: I have bound the function add() to the button number 1 like so: var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");   btn1.addEventListener("click", add);  I have waited a bit for the script to be loaded, before hitting the second button.

Actually, there is something I have not precised... It is that I have tested it on a very simple html doc in my browser and it worked just fine. Exactly like I have explained it in this very post. The real context of application (where it does not work) is in a Chrome extension... And I cannot seem to figure why...

Comment: I had a very similar problem recently regarding a chrome extension injecting script. I opted to just copy and paste the entire file contents into the injected script. Sorta hacky but it works.

Comment: I think that goes beyond sort of hacky...

Comment: It clearly is a bit too much hacky for me ^^'...

Comment: If it helps you at all, the reason this problem exists is that chrome extensions exist in a process outside the webpage. Because of this, your window object is different, and when you inject a script element, the script is loaded to the page's window object. You can not share objects between the page easily. You could inject your content-script into a script tag on the page. You could fire an event passing the library object and listen for that event in your content-script. The standard way to do this is not to use cdn but include the library in your extension files.

Comment: Ok! It helps me a lot. I was not sure about the deeper mechanism that you have just explained. I will try to convince my client to add the library without any cdn.

Answer (score 0):

One `hacky` solution is to just include the entire script in your function. i.e.

```js
function add() {
/*!
 * Chart.js v2.9.4
 * https://www.chartjs.org
 * (c) 2020 Chart.js Contributors
 * Released under the MIT License
 */
//The entire contents of https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js pasted here
}
```

Comment: It might work for sure, but I cannot afford it, I have to deliver a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: What do you mean by cleaner? It takes less time for my extension to load things this way than to use cdn.

Comment: I am sorry if I was offending. I did not mean to. I am sure it shows better performances but I am not sure my client would appreciate it to be fully included in their current code...

Comment: No offence taken, I am more just asking what you meant by cleaner. If your client has criteria by which you must design your code, then it would be useful to understand those criteria in forming a better answer.

Comment: I am glad there was no miscomprehension here. I will try this and probably declare your suggestion as the definite answer if I manage to get it working.

Comment: Sounds good, if you have more criteria I am happy to revise / form another answer. There are many ways to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 0):

Just add html script element, before the your script is evaluated.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
function draw() {
    // your draw function 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: I can't add the script this way. Since my context of execution is a Chrome extension, I have no other way but to use
`document.createElement("script")`